# How is params p added in product listing url on click of pagination?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, pagination, toolbar

I Need to know how  **www.example.com?p=5** added in magento2 URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### **?p=2**
>
> here **p** is parameter and **2** is a value.

**p indicate page and value 2 indicate page 2**

**it comes when you click on this**
[image]

> You can check it using **Inspect Element (F12)**

[image]

For more [click here](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-pagination.html)

Comment: Is any  javascript related click function ?

Comment: Magento provide Paging component. No  any javascript call.

Comment: What if i want to add custom param similar to p ? Like instead of p if i want change name ?

Comment: Your custom param and magento param same  then both get same value.